# Best practice Google Scripts with two functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm not sure what my issue is here. I have an office visitor sign in/out Google spreadsheet. This is how I'm trying to get it to work. When a visitor selects a checkbox in the "in" column a timestamp will display in the next column. When a visitor selects a checkbox in the "out" column a timestamp will display in the next column. Currently this is how it's working: When I have only the first function in the code editor a timestamp displays in column 4 - like it's supposed to. When I add the second function a timestamp displays in column 6, but not in column 4. It's like the second function is overriding the first. What would correct the issue?

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "SignInOut" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}

function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "SignInOut" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions have the same name, so it will run the last.

Perhaps you can avoid having to define 2 times the same function, try something like:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(), r, colCell, nextCell;
  if(s.getName() === 'SignInOut') { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    r = e.range; //s.getActiveCell();
    colCell = r.getColumn();
    if(colCell === 3 || colCell === 5) { //checks the column
      nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if(nextCell.getValue() === '') //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. For future reference what is the function name?